# Is there a canonical way to sync query params in the url (angular-ui-router) with variables on a scope with two-way binding?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here is an example implementation of what I mean:
http://plnkr.co/edit/iwQPZfbDyKYwSzjjAPTN?p=preview

Bound one way:

1. Given you have the plunkr loaded with preview
2. When you change the text in the bottom input containing only "fooDefault"
3. Then you can see both query parameter in the url and the value on scope update all at

And also the other way:

1. Given you have the plunkr loaded with preview
2. When you change the text in the top input containing "#/a?foo=fooDefault"
3. Then you can see both query parameter in the url and the value on scope update all at once

Most relevant code section (StackOverflow asked me to include one):

```
.factory('syncUrlWithScope', function ($location) {
  return function ($scope, defaultValues) {
    $scope.$watch(function () {
      return $location.search()
    }, function (newVal) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(defaultValues), 'from url to scope', newVal)
      $scope.queryParams = newVal
    }, true)

    $scope.$watch('queryParams', function (newVal) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(defaultValues), 'from scope to url', newVal, defaultValues)
      for (var key in defaultValues) if (defaultValues.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        $scope.queryParams[key] = $scope.queryParams[key] || defaultValues[key]
      }
      $location.replace()
      $location.search($scope.queryParams)
    }, true)
  }
})
.controller('ctrl1', function ($scope, syncUrlWithScope) {
  syncUrlWithScope($scope, {foo: 'fooDefault'})
})
.controller('ctrl2', function ($scope, syncUrlWithScope) {
  syncUrlWithScope($scope, {bar: 'barDefault'})
})
```

As you can see, I use 2 watchers to bind 'from url to scope' and also 'from scope to url'.

But there is an issue with it:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1840

Is there a better way for achieving the same kind of two-way binding without encountering that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have my view react on search params changed on both js side and manually via url manipulation i had something like:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
    console.log('$locationChangeSuccess LogsController');
    $scope.searchParams = parseSearchToTags($location.search());
    ... do something with params ...
});
```

Comment: Success! http://plnkr.co/edit/EWv3ioJXqHIi7VmJp3Hs?p=preview Thanks. I am still not sure whether this is the best solution though. I have the nagging feeling that watching `$location.search()` should work too. Anyways, I am accepting your answer as solution for now unless/until something better might come along.